# npm install bootstrap@4.0.0 command gives ENETUNREACH error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap

[image: my ubuntu terminal]

I successfully used the create-react-app command, and the npm start command worked. But when I tried to install the bootstrap using `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0 --save`, it gave an "ENETUNREACH" error. I am using npm version 5.8.0, nodejs version 10.15.2 and Ubuntu 19.10
P.S. I am a complete beginner, and I am following an online react course.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Your network in unreachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you are behind a proxy, you could do this

```
npm config set proxy null
npm config set https-proxy null
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

The first two lines will remove proxy's if there any.

Third line will make npm download from the official package registry.

here's an article you could read on [How to run npm Behind A Proxy Server - a step-by-step guide](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/how-to-run-npm-behind-a-proxy-server-a-step-by-step-guide/19386)

It looks like current installed `npm` is not compatible with Node.js version you are using. You’ll probably need to update your npm using

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```